# Using ReactJS Apps on Mobile Devices

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question but not sure where else to post it either.

I am trying to build an app using ReactJS instead of ReactNative knowing very well that users mostly are going to be mobile users. Is there any article documenting the user experience when the app was not native ? I do not have resources to build a native app yet so I can't use ReactNative for now.

Comment: have you check ionic with reactjs or other framework with reactjs

Comment: try learn about responsive web design and that way you could make it in react and it will have sort of look & feel of a native app